# Routing for multiple themes in php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have nuilt a website in php and have made so that it can have multiple themes. What i have done so far is in main root index.php page i have:

```
<?php
include "config_inc.php";
?>
<?php
include "themes/{$aset=['Theme']}/index.php";
?>
```

In the config_inc file i have the conection to database so that {$aset=['Theme']} can view the theme that has been selected from backend.

from my main root i have the folder theme that contains all my themes with in it and in each theme its appropiate css files and theme files.

My problem is that when you visit my site the main index does include the index.php file from the theme selected and shows as mydomain.com but however when i click on a link lets say contact us it will display the URL as mydoain.com/themes/clear/contactus.php and not mydomain.com/contactus

I have tried a few things in the .htaccess file for uri but nothing has worked, my last attempt was:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^themes/clear(/.+)$ /$1 [R=302,L,NC]
```

Any help is appreciated thanks

Comment: Wait, what is this supposed to be `{$aset=['Theme']}`?  Is `$aset` an array`?  Please post the output of `print_r($aset);`  What would happen if PHP allowed arbitrary evaluation inside `{}` is that the variable `$aset` would be assigned the one-element array literal containing the string `'Theme'` (if you have PHP 5.4+).  But PHP doesn't evaluate that way in `{}`.

Comment: I suspect you might just mean to use `$aset['Theme']`...

Comment: aset uses the select from database so that i can retrieve the name of the theme being used. $qset = "select * from re_settings";
$rset = mysql_query($qset) or die(mysql_error());
$aset = mysql_fetch_array($rset);

Comment: the aset part works and i can control the themes from backend. It works by getting the theme name from database and adding it to the path themes/theme_name/index.php what i want is to remove the themes/themesname from the url